# DocumentDB data structure misunderstanding

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm starting a new website project and i would like to use DocumentDB as database instead of traditional RDBMS.

I will need two kind of documents to store:

1. User documents, they will hold all the user data.
2. Survey documents, that will hold all data about survays.

**May i put both kind in a single collection or should i create one collection for each?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you do this is totally up to you - it's a fairly broad question, and there are good reasons for combining, and good reasons for separating. But *objectively*, you'll have some specific things to consider:

- Each collection has its own cost footprint (starting around $24 per collection).
- Each collection has its own performance (RU capacity) and storage limit.
- Documents within a collection do *not* have to be homogeneous - each document can have whatever properties you want. You'll likely want some type of identification property that you can query on, to differentiate document types, should you store them all in a single collection.
- Transactions are collection-scoped. So, for example, if you're building server-side stored procedures and need to modify content across your `User` and `Survey` documents, you need to keep this in mind.

Comment: Yes, i saw that a collection starts from about 24$ (+taxes) and the first thing i thought was "Waw is not that cheap!".

Comment: My first idea of possible solution was similar to your, i can probably insert a kind of class identifier (User or Survey) in each document and using it for filtering the documents with queries.

Comment: But i'm not sure what this mean in terms of performance, of course this will increase a bit the amount of code but also will worsen query performance?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but let's not turn this into a discussion. You can easily try out your queries and measure their RU cost. As I originally stated, your question is fairly broad - lots of things to consider. I mapped out the major things that, objectively, will impact this choice.